# What happens if i assign object to another object of different class?

Tags: java, object, compiler-errors

Here is my code :

```
class A
{
    int x=2,y=3;
}
class B extends A
{
    //Blank 
}
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A a=new A();
        B b;
        b=a;
        System.out.println(b.x);
        System.out.println(b.y);
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to run this code, "incompatible types: A can't be converted to B" Error is shown.

And also when i'm trying to type-cast "a" into "B", ClassCastException is occured.

Is there any way to assign object to another object of different class in java ?

Comment: No. You cannot assign an object of type `A` to a variable of type `B`, because it _is not_ a `B`. You _can_ assign an object of type `B` to a variable of type `A`, because `B` extends `A`.

Comment: long explanation short: every B is an A, not every A is a B

Comment: Why would there be a way to do that? That's essentially allowing something that is designed to fail. The very point of a programming languages is to not allow things that we know will fail. Otherwise, we wouldn't use programming languages, we'd write in assembly.

Comment: `b=a` isn't allowed because not all `A` objects are `B` objects.  Even though all `B`s are also `A`s, you can still have objects that are  only `A`s but not `B`s, and thus `b=a` might be trying to assign a non-`B` object to a `B` variable.   But `a=b` _would_ be allowed, precisely because every `B` object is also an `A` object, so `a=b` is always assigning an `A` object to an `A` variable.

Comment: @kumesana looking at it from a non-OO background, considering only data-structs, it *would* make sense (see slicing etc.). That this has been solved the way it is in Java (and other OO languages) may not be obvious to a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, a variable of "base class" can be assigned "sub class" but not the other way around. Namely you can have "A a=new B()" but not "B b=new A()".

There is also an intuitive reason. The base class is usually something basic, say "Person", while the subclass is more specific and promises to provide more properties/capabilities e.g. "Teacher" (= person **plus** additional capabilities to teach). You can't force an ordinary Person to magically call itself a teacher, it will just fail the minute you try to activate any teaching capabilities...

We could start a philosophical argument about occasions where the specific thing has less capabilities than the base (e.g. "IncompetentPerson extends Person") but java inheritance is not generally aiming to cover that.